# Django: URL trailing slash issue

Tags: python, django

urls.py

```
url(r'^v1/files/$', MyFileView.as_view(), name='api-upload'),
url(r'^v1/files/$', MyFileView.as_view(), name='api-view-all'),
```

views.py

```
class MyFileView(APIView):
    def post():
        pass
    def get():
        pass
```

My question is: why `POST api/v1/files` works like `GET api/v1/files/`? I thought `POST api/v1/files` should return 404. Anything wrong?

**UPDATE**

But `api/v1/files/<id>` does not have this issue. `api/v1/files/<id>/` will return 404.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that they *don't* "work like `GET`".

What is *really* happening is that:

- you send a `POST url`
- the server replies with a `HTTP 302` to `url/`
- and the browser performs a `GET url/`.

And the result of *that* is what you actually see.

If you check the requests being actually sent along the wire, I suspect you'll see *two* requests - the first being the `POST`, the second being the `GET`.

Comment: @Iserni, Intertesting. never known before. Thanks

Comment: Heh. Neither did I, I had to ask myself. You can't guess the head-scratching: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39848396/1428679 :-D

Comment: But `api/v1/files/<id>` does not have this issue. `api/v1/files/<id>/` will return 404.

Comment: Probably, under the hood, `files` is treated as a directory (and redirects), while `files/id` is treated as a file (and doesn't - nor can it get a further slash). It depends on how the routing is implemented server side.